# Command Line Parser Library .NET being able to retrieve version number

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, command-line, command-line-arguments

I'm working with the NuGet Command Line Parser Library. I want to be able to set up some command line tools and I want the command(-v or --version) to return the current version of the application. I have another method set up to find the version and set it to a string so all I need now is that command line argument to set to that current version rather than just expecting something after the command. thanks for the help!

```
static string GetVersion() { 
    Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
    FileVersionInfo fvi = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(assembly.Location);
    string currentVersion = fvi.FileVersion;
    return currentVersion;
}

class Options 
{
    [Option('v', "version", HelpText = "Sets version to be run")]
    public string Version { get; set; }
}
```

that's just the important parts.

Comment: Have you read the documentation and examples?  What do you have so far and where are you stuck?

Comment: Post the code you've written so far.

Comment: @DStanley so far I have read the documentation and it isn't clear how you set up such an 'option' as they're called in the library. So far, I've set up options that get and set input/output file names and there's an automatic help feature that I've included. I'm stuck on how to call a method from a getter setter option.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding how the "properties" work.  I'll give a code sample.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on the [documentation](http://commandline.codeplex.com/) it looks like you want something like this:

```
// Define a class to receive parsed values
class Options {

  [Option('v', "version", 
    HelpText = "Prints version information to standard output.")]
  public bool Version { get; set; }

  [ParserState]
  public IParserState LastParserState { get; set; }

  [HelpOption]
  public string GetUsage() {
    return HelpText.AutoBuild(this,
      (HelpText current) => HelpText.DefaultParsingErrorsHandler(this, current));
  }
}

// Consume them
static void Main(string[] args) {
  var options = new Options();
  if (CommandLine.Parser.Default.ParseArguments(args, options)) {
    // Values are available here
    if (options.Version) Console.WriteLine("Version: {0}", GetVersion());
  }
}
```

You don't need the `Version` property to get the version - you can just use it as a "switch" to tell the program to display the version.  If you wanted the *user* to set the version then a get/set string property would be more appropriate.